# SQLCMD external editor

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I have set the environment variable SQLCMDEDITOR=gvim to invoke an vim with the ED command of SQLCMD. From my old Windows 7 computer, it used to work.

I have now a new laptop (windows 10) and, when attempting the same thing I get, on the same server:

```
C:\>sqlcmd -S <serverName> 
1> SELECT GETDATE()
2> GO

-----------------------
2019-12-13 09:11:47.493

(1 rows affected)
1> ED
Sqlcmd: Error: Internal error at ExecProcess (Reason: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect).
```

I have checked that gvim is in the PATH. I have tried to set the variable to: gvim; gvim.exe; C:\Progra~2\Vim\vim81\gvim.exe; notepad.exe. Always the same.

Why is that ?

Comment: Thank you for having taken the time to forward this to azure. Let'see how they reply

Comment: I added the bug report link as an answer for visibility. The more votes the better. Development of a fix will depend on priorities. It doesn't seem the external feature is used much, given there wasn't already a bug report filed.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a SQLCMD bug. I can repro with SQLCMD 14.0.3026.27 on Windows 10.

I submitted the bug report on the [SQL Server feedback site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server). Consider upvoting the [bug report](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/39255748-cannot-use-external-editor-with-sqlcmd).